# How do you order by a search phrase found in the beginning of a word and only afterwards the middle using SQL

Tags: sql, search, sorting, sql-like

Let's say I have table [users] with the field [Name] and I've written a query in my application to search by name.

The names in the database are:

Lala
Ally

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE [Name] LIKE '%al%'
```

where 'al' is my search term.

How would I sort the results by search term found in the beginning i.e. '%al' and only afterwards '%al%'.

The result set should be

Ally
Lala

I'm using SQL SERVER.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This will work for all strings as you require assuming you are using sql server-

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE [Name] LIKE '%al%'
ORDER BY PATINDEX('%al%',[Name])
```

Comment: I like this answer, but it didn't work when I tested it. I think the following answer will work.                                   

SELECT [name], PATINDEX('%al%',[name]) from users WHERE [name] like '%al%' ORDER by PATINDEX('%al%',[name])

Comment: SELECT patindex('al','lala') -> 0. SELECT patindex('%al%','lala') -> 2. I just tested on SQL-Server 2005. It looks to me like you need the %al%.

Comment: @Fillet - I am sorry, you are right. You need a %al% in PATINDEX. Thank you for the information. Have edited my answer.

Comment: SQL-Server 2005. I got this message "'PATHINDEX' is not recognized an an integrated function". I think it should be PATINDEX. After I removed the H it ran, but I think it needs the % to do the order correctly.

Comment: OK, now it works. Upvote from me now, as it's simple and general.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 0, [Name] FROM users WHERE [Name] LIKE 'al%'

UNION

SELECT 1, [Name] FROM users WHERE [Name] LIKE '%al%'
  AND NOT [Name] LIKE 'al%'

ORDER BY
  1, 2
```

Comment: If you have values Ally,Lally,bbally then this will return you results as Ally,bbally,Lally whereas the OP needs it in Ally,Lally,bbally order.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports it, I guess you could wrap your select in another select that uses index_of on the name, such as:

```
select index_of('al', Name) as sortorder, * from (select * FROM users WHERE [Name] LIKE '%al%')
order by sortorder
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ended up with this query variant for SQLite doing same, search term is "jeff":

```
SELECT name
 FROM details WHERE name LIKE 'jeff%' OR name LIKE '%jeff%' 
    ORDER BY (0 - (name LIKE 'jeff%') + (name LIKE '%jeff%')) || name 
    LIMIT 100;
```